# Why limit the maximum size of deposit-CBDC transfers?

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, central-banking, cbdc

From page 33 of Dirk Niepelt's [Money and Banking with Reserves and CBDC](https://www.vwi.unibe.ch/unibe/portal/fak_wiso/b_dep_vwl/a_inst_vwl/content/e195818/e195991/e556277/e1283995/dp2212_ger.pdf) (October 2022):

> Some central banks consider caps on CBDC balances to limit the maximum size of deposit-CBDC transfers ("digital bank runs"). In an environment with heterogeneous households such caps could allow to target monetary policy if CBDC paid a higher interest rate than deposits and "poor" savers only held CDC balances below the cap while "rich" savers held CBDC up to the cap as well as deposits. In such a situation the interest rate on CBDC would only have a direct substitution effect on the consumption and liquidity choices of poor savers.

I cannot understand this. Also, why would this policy be implemented? Please explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1-In one of the digital pound papers (sorry, I don't remember which) it's written:

> *Why do we need a limit for how many digital pounds I can hold?*
> If we introduced a digital pound, we think we would need to set a limit
> for how much people could hold. This would give us the time to
> understand the impact that it might have on the financial system and
> help us ensure it wouldn't cause disruption.
> Once we better
> understand this and how people use it, we would review this limit.
> We've not yet decided what the limit would be, but it would be high
> enough for day-to -day spending. So you would receive all sorts of
> payments, such as your salary, without worrying.

2-It's also  explained in this speech to be from 10,000-20,000£ (I'm afraid in a similar reasoning that is not clear for you)
https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/speech/2023/february/jon-cunliffe-speech-at-uk-finance-update-on-central-bank-digital-currency

3-To be honest, I study CBDC from Computer Science & Engineering perspective; ie, I cannot explain the above in better words for you, but I know 2 other reasons that were mentioned in my field:

-***To minimize the risks of money laundry*** (if your transactions are less than a certain threshold you can be execluded from AML investigations and keep your anonymity usually associated with crypto)

-***To minimize the risk of Distributed Denial of Service attacks*** (think of it like gas limit in Ethereum: a max on spending and number of transactions, especially in offline payments, minimize the risk of DDoS attacks)
More details can be found here
https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2021/11/4-key-threats-central-bank-digital-currencies/